# Lie algebra of the Quaternion group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

How can we deduce that the Lie algebra of the multiplicative group of quaternions $Q^*= Q/\{0\}$ is just $Q$ equipped with its vector space structure over $R$ and the bracket:

$[q_1,q_2] = q_1q_2 - q_2q_1$

We define the Lie algebra of a Lie Group as being the vector space $V$ over a field  $F$, equipped with a bilinear map, the Lie bracket, such that:

1. $ \forall X \in V$ :  $[X,X]=0$
2. $ \forall X, Y ,Z \in V$ it satisfies the Jacobi identity

We also know that every one-parameter subgroup ( morphism from ($\mathbb{R},+)$ to the Lie Group $Q^*$ ) of $Q^*$ is of the form:

$$ x \longrightarrow \exp(xq)$$

Comment: That depends on what "we" know already. For example, how do you define the Lie algebra of a Lie group? Certain invariant vector fields? Tangent space at identity? Something more algebraic if things are written as matrices? Do we know the Lie algebras of other Lie groups and can we use that? Without such info about what prerequisites we are allowed to use, your question is hard to answer, because it is easy to answer: "It is well known it's true."

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, but that edit is not sufficient, unfortunately. You gave the definition of *a* Lie algebra. See how that definition does not involve any info about a specific Lie group. The question is how do you know a specific Lie algebra belongs to a specific Lie group. (And the last sentence about one-parameter groups has little to do with Lie algebras, unless in the source you're using those are used for the Lie group-Lie algebra correspondence.)

Answer (score 2):

$Q^*$ is a subgroup of $Gl(4,\mathbb{R})$ and its Lie algebra is a Lie subalgebra of $M(4,\mathbb{R})$, if $q_1,q_2\in Q$,is in the Lie algebra of $Q^*$ and the restriction of the Lie bracket to $Q$ is $[q_1,q_2]=q_1q_2-q_2q_1$.